# How to wire a ceiling fan to one switch with 2 cables

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

If I have 2 cables, both with hot, neutral, and ground running from one box and a ceiling fan and light that will be on separate switches in one wall box, do I hook up blue to black, black to black, all 3 whites and all 3 grounds?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't completely clear what you mean; would you add a diagram to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: My bad, I thought I did, but I missed something I guess. I’ve got 2 cables, both with 3 wires coming from the junction box in the ceiling. I’ve got one fan with a blue, a black, a white, and a green coming from it. The wall box had a switch for the fan and the light on my last one. Those were the only switches for each though. I tried to upload a pic but I don’t think it worked. My question was do I treat the black from each cable as my 2 hots and hook one to blue fan and one to black fan and put all 3 whites together and all grounds together. Sorry it’s so long winded.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: You're still not stating clearly whether power comes into the fan box, or the switch box.  Does the fan have 2 white wires?

Comment: how you do it is figure out what wires go where and then figure out what connections are needed for correct operation. we need more information to answer your question.